# Java standalone to web

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, web, desktop-application

Suppose I have a standalone java application. Now I want to enable multiple clients to access it via network or web (HTTP or web services). What is the best approach to convert a standalone app to an app that can be remotely accessed? Are there any simple frameworks that you recommend? Any best practise?

Comment: [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java tutorial on sockets, [All about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html), might help. This is if you want your java application to be a server of some sort. The tutorial shows you how to connect to your java application using a ServerSocket (in the tutorial they write a client that connects to the server as well). When you have a basic understanding of sockets it's a small step to, for example, start handling HTTP requests (tutorials on this are easily found on the web as well).

Answer (score 1):

> [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Comment: do you recommend JWS for apps that fetch data from mysql and returns it online?

Comment: The desktop app. *should **not** have direct access to the DB.*  Instead it should be forced to access it through a web service.  This is for the protection of the DB itself.